# Where can I place prototype property as per my below code?

Tags: javascript, function, oop, properties, prototype

I have writtern this two different ways and both giving me same result , so which I can use when ?

**FIRST EXAMPLE**

```
var BaseCls = function() {
  BaseCls.prototype.name = "John";
};
var JustCls = new BaseCls();
console.log(JustCls.name); // This is giving result John
```

**SECOND EXAMPLE**

```
var BaseCls = function() {};
BaseCls.prototype.name = "John";
var JustCls = new BaseCls();
console.log(JustCls.name); // This is also giving result John
```

Both giving me same result so I just want to know is there any other criteria which lead to write this property / method with prototype inside / outside main function ?

Thanks for consideration

Comment: the first "pattern" is never used by anyone

Answer (score 1):

You should change prototype only outside the constructor.
Otherwise you change it every time you create an instance.